# Samsung S6 keep showing Device Security "1 threat detected"

Tags: security, lost-phone

I have found the App "androidlost" to be very useful in order to be able to found my lost phone  ...

But on my Samsung S6, I keep getting Device Security "1 threat detected" regarding this App and they tell me to remove it. Please how can I remove this notification because I want to keep this App.

[image: Screenshot]

References:

[Lost Android at google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=fr)

https://www.androidlost.com

Comment: I have slightly rephrased the title of the question

Comment: @xavier_fakerat thanks :) However Do you know any solution to try

Comment: It is most likely a  false positive, or Samsung prefers that users   use their services, rather than a third party application

Comment: Find out what app is showing that notification, and remove it... There is a 99.999% chance there is no "threat" but this is a scare tactic to get you to buy or install something. Unacceptable app behavior, remove it and leave a negative review.

Comment: @acejavelin I know the App and I like it , I wan to keep it but just remove the noification

Comment: @TheBeast What app? Either disable the specific notification in the app, or go to App Settings and remove the entire apps ability to do notifications.

Comment: @acejavelin it's called androidlost, the notification is raised by samsung device security and that's what I want to remove from always appearing on my screen

Comment: @TheBeast The author seems responsive to issues, ask here: http://groups.google.com/group/androidlost

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround provided at XDA forums which involves disabling the security log agent. I believe it is also the cause for the "Threat detected" alert notification.

1. Install free [Package Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ospolice.packagedisabler&hl=en) from Google Play Store.
2. Launch this app, search and disable "Security Log Agent".

Doesn't need root :)

This should fix  this annoying notification again.

Reference

1. [Unauthorized actions have been detected. error](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6-edge/help/unauthorized-actions-detected-error-t3121228/page4)